# Converting RleViews to a matrix

Tags: r, bioconductor

Is there a faster way to convert a RleViews object (which contains elements of the same length) to a matrix object?

I usually use

```
viewApply(x, as.vector)
```

Tnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reproducible example

```
library(IRanges)  ## Bioconductor
rle = Rle(sample(2, 100000, TRUE))
v = successiveViews(rle, rep(5, 1000), gap=10)
```

and then maybe

```
r = seqselect(rle, start(v), end(v))
matrix(as.integer(r), nrow=5)
```

If you provide your own example and timings then it would be possible to ask whether this is an improvement or not.

**Update 29 July 2016**

The coercion to matrix can be accomplished by `unlist()`ing the views, and invoking matrix,

```
matrix(unlist(v), nrow=5)
```

This works in part because `matrix()` coerces its first argument to a vector.

Comment: seqselect seems not to exist anymore?